# getting Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. after adding MapActivity

Tags: android, build, runtime-error

I am getting following error when I run application. I started getting this error after I added MapActivity to project. I have added my gradle file at bottom.

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug
:app:dexDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)","sources":[{}]}


 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 48.477 secs
```

This is my gradle file...

`apply plugin: com.android.application

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.gandivainc.androidcontrols"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Here are possible fixes:

1) change the `buildToolsVersion` to a version level greater than or equal to the compilation and target SDK.  See [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#buildFileBasics) link for detailed info.
So in your case it should be something like this:

```
android { 
    compileSdkVersion 23 
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0' // must be greater than or equal to compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion
}
```

2) The targetSdkVersion attribute does indeed affect an application's runtime behavior.

Depending on what you set it to will determine whether compatibility features are enabled/disabled in the Android framework.
try changing the `targetSdkVersion` to level 23 same as your `compiledSdkVersion`.

3) **Make sure you have don't have any similar dependencies in libs folder as defined in build.gradle**.
If so, then there are chances that the dependency in libs folder may overlap with dependencies defined in the build.gradle file.

**Solution** : if there is any duplicate .jar file then remove it from the lib folder and `rebuild` the project

4) In your packagingOptions  try adding

```
exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
```

and sync the project

Hope it helps!